# color correction and calibration

Tags: color, display

I have a problem with color correction and calibration. I have x-rite display pro, but don't know how I could use by synchronizing it with matlab or python. In the website "Software support includes a low-level ANSI C API, MATLAB/Octave and Python libraries for use under Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows, and Linux." is written, but I could not find libraries. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think X-Rite provides a developer API to retail customers. According to their own [specifications page for the i1Display Pro](http://www.xrite.com/categories/calibration-profiling/i1display-pro), it lists:

> Software Development Kit — available for OEM customers

The only reference to developer APIs I could find was at an [OEM retailer's site](http://vpixx.com/products/tools-for-vision-sciences/calibration-system/x-rite-i1display/) (vpixx.com), which has the statement you quoted,

> Software support includes a low-level ANSI C API, MATLAB/Octave and Python libraries for use under Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows, and Linux.

It seems there's two possibilities here:

1. Vpixx.com just republished X-Rite's OEM "sell-sheet" information, and doesn't actually provide a developer API; or
2. Vpixx.com wraps/adapts X-Rite's OEM SDK with their own API that they provide to their customers.

If you bought from vpixx.com, then you should try contacting them for access to the API. If you didn't buy from them, chances are they will not provide you the API.